# How do I insert this php tag into jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to insert a php tag in between the opening and closing div tags below. Can anyone help me understand how to insert `<?php the_field('200_200_1', 'option'); ?>` in there?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('<div class="video_gallery_ad"></div>').appendTo('#avs_gallery');

});
```

Edit: This is a JS file.

Edit2: Since this won't work with a JS file, I moved it into my `functions.php` file (using WordPress). Below is the snippet I have in my `functions.php` file. Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('<div class="video_gallery_ad"><?php the_field('200_200_1', 'option'); ?></div>').appendTo('#avs_gallery');

});
```

Comment: Like this: `$('<div class="video_gallery_ad"><?php the_field('200_200_1', 'option'); ?></div>').appendTo('#avs_gallery');`?  If this is in a `.php` file, that should work (assuming `the_field()` echos something).

Comment: As this looks like Wordpress, you should generally speaking put your script in a file, add it with dependencies using `enque_script`, and use `localize_script` to pass the PHP value. That is the proper way to do this.

Comment: @Rocket It's a js file. Sorry, should have mentioned.

Comment: .js files aren't parsed by PHP unless you explicitly set PHP to parse .js files.

Comment: @Desi then it isn't possible without modifications to your webserver.

Comment: @adeneo @Kevin thank you. I moved the snippet into my `functions.php` file (yes it is WordPress, btw); however, I'm still not seeing any results. I pasted what I have right now in the post above. Any help in getting me to understand this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would you stick jQuery in your themes functions.php file, that's not the right place for it. Look up localize_script in the Wordpress and figure out how you pass PHP generated content to javascript file.

Comment: @Desi: What the heck were you thinking, deleting the body of the question in [revision 4](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21054356/4)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
$('<div class="video_gallery_ad"><?php the_field('200_200_1', 'option'); ?></div>').appendTo('#avs_gallery');
```

But it is VERY risky. Isn't it better to render render output of this function in some hidden div and after that load its content into `#avs_gallery` ?

And JS:

```
$('#hiddenAdv').show().appendTo('#avs_gallery');
```

Comment: @RohitAgrawal Easy, configure your webserver to send .js files to the php parser. (note, that generally is a bad idea)